# ZeroMQ: Why was a ZeroMQ test on IPC transport-class slower than on TCP loopback endpoint?

Tags: zeromq

I performed the same test with same data size and same number of messages once with IPC endpoint and once with TCP loopback address and I saw a significant difference in the time for the data transport.
1) Isn't TCP supposed to be slower because of the network stack?
2) Does this have to do with pyzmq library?

Comment: You might already know about **StackOverflow explicit and strict requirement to post MCVE-based questions**. Kindly review and update your post so as to contain the full MCVE ( capable of such test-run replication ) and add your System-under-Test details ( incl. O/S version, native / VM-wrapped modus-operandi, capacities et al, incl. the type of the system's clock, that was used to measure test-run(s) ).